# JavaScript: for loop in dynamic rollover function not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to create a dynamic function using a for-loop in javascript, which will fire rollovers. I am using JS vs. CSS as the amount of images which will be rollovers is growing, and I figure a function is easier to maintain than x number of selectors.

This is creating a `on method` similar to jQuery.

```
var on = function(event, elem, callback, capture) {
  if (typeof elem === 'function') {
    capture = callback;
    callback = elem;
    elem = window;
  }
  capture = capture ? true : false;
  elem = typeof elem === 'string' ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
  if (!elem) return;
  elem.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
};
```

These are my `rollOver` and `rollOut` functions:

```
function rollOver(elem) {
  document.getElementById(elem).src = `/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_${elem.slice(length-1)}.jpg?$staticlink$`
}

function rollOut(elem) {
  document.getElementById(elem).src = `/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_${elem.slice(length-1)}.jpg?$staticlink$`
}
```

And this is where my for-loop lives:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      var rollOverCollectionA = document.getElementById('roll-over-collection-a').querySelectorAll('img');
          rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);

          for (var i = 0; i < rollOverCollectionA.length; i++) {
           on('mouseover', rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function(){
             console.log( rollOverCollectionA[i].id)
             rollOver(rollOverCollectionA[i].id);
           });

           on('mouseout', rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function(){
            rollOut(rollOverCollectionA[i].id);
           }); 
          }

    });
```

Comment: In ${elem.slice(length-1)}, where that length come from ? Maybe you needs elem.slice(elem.length-1)

Comment: Ahh, yes! Thank you, unfortunately that didn't help!

Comment: Will document.querySelector  work on an id if you don't prepend '#'?

Answer (score 1):

The main problems I saw were:

- `elem.slice(length - 1);` should be `elem.slice(elem.length - 1)` otherwise you're subtracting 1 from undefined
- `elem.slice` should be replaced with `elem.substr(elem.lastIndexOf('-') + 1)` otherwise any images over 9 will start back at 0 because you would only get the last character of the id.
- When you pass a string as `elem` to `on`, it uses `document.querySelector`, but you pass the id without the hash symbol (`#`). You don't need this anyway as you already have a reference to the image element, you can just pass that.

I also tidied it up and modernized it a little bit.

The glaring problem I neglected to mention was the use of var and the `for(;;)` loop. Thanks to @tranktor53 for pointing that out. I always instinctively replace `for(;;)` loops with `for...in` or `for...of` loops where I see them, and var with let or const, I didn't even notice that it was part of the problem.

```js
function on({ type, element = window, callback, capture = false }) {
  if (typeof element === 'string') element = document.querySelector(element);
  if (!element) return;
  element.addEventListener(type, callback, capture);
};
function rollOver({ element, id }) {
  element.src = `https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=${ id }+hover`;
}
function rollOut({ element, id }) {
  element.src = `https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=${ id }+no+hover`;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _ => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#roll-over-collection-a img');
  for(let element of elements) {
    const id = element.id.substr(element.id.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
    on({ type: 'mouseover', element, callback: _ => rollOver({ element, id }) });
    on({ type: 'mouseout' , element, callback: _ => rollOut({ element, id }) });
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="roll-over-collection-a">
  <img id="roll-over-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=1+no+hover">
  <img id="roll-over-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=2+no+hover">
  <img id="roll-over-3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=3+no+hover">
  <img id="roll-over-4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=4+no+hover">
  <img id="roll-over-5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=5+no+hover">
  <img id="roll-over-6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=6+no+hover">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is using `var` in the `for` loop and assuming that the value of `i` seen in the event handler will match that of `i` when th call back function was created. This is incorrect, since `i` will have the value it reached when the `for` loop completed, at a later time when the handler gets executed.

In current browsers the solution is to use `let` instead of `var` and hence starting the loop as

```
for (let i = 0; i < rollOverCollectionA.length; i++) ...
```

For discussion and older solutions see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/5217142)

In regards the image source string calculation

`/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_${elem.slice(length-1)}.jpg?$staticlink$`

please review what is needed - if you need to copy the entire value of `elem` as a string, don't include the call to `slice`. If a part of the string is required, the posted code may be correct. Slicing from a start index of `elem.length-1` will copy the last letter of the element id (of course) and may also be correct.

---

*Update:* The need to capture the value of `i` during loop iteration can be eliminated in at least two ways:

1. In the mouseover and mouseout event handlers replace `rollOverCollectionA[i]`with `this`. There is no need for reverse lookup of an HTML collection based on a captured index value to determine the element an event handler is attached to.
2. Use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/5217142) with a single listener attached to on the images' DOM container. Using the same `on` function, and `elem.id.slice(length-1)` as a possible image source suffix, similar to:

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
       var rollOverCollectionA = document.getElementById('roll-over-collection-a');
       on('mouseover', rollOverCollectionA, function( event){
           var elem = event.target;
           if( elem && elem.id && elem.tagName === 'IMG') {
                elem.src = `/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_HOVER_${elem.id.slice(length-1)}.jpg?$staticlink$`;
       }
       });
       on('mouseout', rollOverCollectlonA, function(event) {
           var elem = event.target;
           if( elem && elem.id && elem.tagName === 'IMG') {
                elem.src = `/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_${elem.id.slice(length-1)}.jpg?$staticlink$`;
           }
       });

   });
   ```